# Timing animations for Tower of Hanoi Visualizer

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am currently building a tower of Hanoi Visualizer. The idea is that you input a number, an algorithm creates the disks and then you can see him moving the disks until the Tower is finished. So far everything works great, the only problem is, that I can't seem to make the animations work.

I tried to run a timeout funciton before each of the style changements, but whenever I clicked on submit, I only saw the end result and no animations. The result I'm looking for is to see each disk get lifted up, dragged to the destination peg and then get dropped.

I think the problem is, that the created elements get rendered last and therefore alreays have the css properties from the end. However, I could of course be wrong as I don't know anything about timing animaitons.

Here is the link to this project. The CSS is just for representation, I know it looks bad :)

https://jsfiddle.net/jakob_mayerhofer/rgx17hps/12/

```
//get submit values
const submit = document.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0];
var numberInput = document.getElementsByClassName('number')[0];
const tower1 = document.getElementsByClassName('tower1')[0];

submit.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  const number = parseInt(numberInput.value);
  towerOfHanoi(number);
  numberInput.value = "";
  e.preventDefault();
});


//start the game
async function towerOfHanoi(number){
  const a = [];
  const b = [];
  const c = [];
  let iterator = number;

//fill first tower with disks equal to number imput
  for(iterator; iterator > 0; iterator--){
    a.push(iterator);
  }

// create the disks
  a.forEach((item) => {
    element = document.createElement("div");
    element.className = "disk";
    element.setAttribute("id", item);
    const style = {
      width: 400/(number+1)*item + "px",
      bottom: a.indexOf(item)*10 + "px",
      background: "rgb(" +Math.floor(Math.random()*256) +"," +Math.floor(Math.random()*256) +"," +Math.floor(Math.random()*256) +")",
      transform: "translateX(0px)"
    }
    Object.assign(element.style, style);
    tower1.appendChild(element);
  });

// this moves the disks
  if(number%2 != 0){
    while(c.length < number){
      moveDisk(a, c, c, number, 2);
      moveDisk(a, b, c, number, 1);
      moveDisk(b, c, c, number, 1)
      console.log(a, b, c);
    }
  }else {
    while(c.length < number){
      moveDisk(a, b, c, number, 1);
      moveDisk(a, c, c, number, 2);
      moveDisk(b, c, c, number, 1);
      console.log(a, b, c);
    }
  }
};



// move disk function, parameters are start, destination, finsh peg and distance between start and destination
function moveDisk(a, b, c, number, distance) {
    if (c.length == number) return;

    if(!a.length && b.length){
      draw(b, a, distance*-1);
      a.push(b[b.length-1]);
      b.pop();
    } else if (!b.length && a.length) {
      draw(a, b, distance);
      b.push(a[a.length-1]);
      a.pop();

    } else {
      if(a[a.length-1] < b[b.length-1]){
        while(a[a.length-1] < b[b.length-1]){
          draw(a, b, distance);
          b.push(a[a.length-1]);
          a.pop();
        }

      } else if(b[b.length-1] < a[a.length-1]){
        while(b[b.length-1] < a[a.length-1]){
          draw(b, a, distance*-1);
          a.push(b[b.length-1]);
          b.pop();
        }
      }
    }
};

//moving function: this should animate the disks
function draw(a, b, distance){
  num = a[a.length-1].toString();
  disk = document.getElementById(num);

//get current translateX css value and then add the distance between start and destination peg
  regEx = /\.*translateX\((.*)px\)/i;
  translate = disk.getAttribute('style')
  value = parseInt(regEx.exec(translate)[1]) + (distance*400);

//move disk up 
  disk.style.bottom = "385px";
//move disk to the destination peg
  disk.style.transform = "translateX(" + value +"px)";
//drop disk
  disk.style.bottom = b.length*20 +"px";

};
```

If you have any suggestions to improve my code, I'm of course happy to receive any Feedback.

I'm thankful for every bit of advice I can get.

Comment: I don't see any code that would introduce a delay somewhere... Just using `async` is not going to do anything useful if you don't have promises you await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has nothing that introduces delays/pauses. Just defining a function as `async` is not going to do anything useful without a promise being awaited inside of it.

Steps to get it working:

1. Define a function that returns a promise that resolves some given time later:

   ```
   const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
   ```
2. Make `draw` an `async` function, and add delays between each change of style:

   ```
   //move disk up 
   disk.style.bottom = "385px";
   await delay(250);
   //move disk to the destination peg
   disk.style.transform = "translateX(" + value +"px)";
   await delay(250);
   //drop disk
   disk.style.bottom = b.length*20 +"px";
   await delay(250);
   ```
3. Make `moveDisk` an `async` function, and where you call `draw`, prefix it with `await`, like for instance:

   ```
   await draw(b, a, distance*-1);
   ```

   Do this wherever you call `draw`.
4. Wherever you call `moveDisk`, also await its promise to resolve, like for instance:

   ```
   await moveDisk(a, c, c, number, 2);
   ```

   Do this wherever you call `moveDisk`.

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

//get submit values
const submit = document.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0];
var numberInput = document.getElementsByClassName('number')[0];
const tower1 = document.getElementsByClassName('tower1')[0];

submit.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  const number = parseInt(numberInput.value);
  towerOfHanoi(number);
  numberInput.value = "";
  e.preventDefault();
});


//start the game
async function towerOfHanoi(number){
  const a = [];
  const b = [];
  const c = [];
  let iterator = number;

//fill first tower with disks equal to number imput
  for(iterator; iterator > 0; iterator--){
    a.push(iterator);
  }

// create the disks
  a.forEach((item) => {
    element = document.createElement("div");
    element.className = "disk";
    element.setAttribute("id", item);
    const style = {
      width: 400/(number+1)*item + "px",
      bottom: a.indexOf(item)*10 + "px",
      background: "rgb(" +Math.floor(Math.random()*256) +"," +Math.floor(Math.random()*256) +"," +Math.floor(Math.random()*256) +")",
      transform: "translateX(0px)"
    }
    Object.assign(element.style, style);
    tower1.appendChild(element);
  });

// this moves the disks
  if(number%2 != 0){
    while(c.length < number){
      await moveDisk(a, c, c, number, 2);
      await moveDisk(a, b, c, number, 1);
      await moveDisk(b, c, c, number, 1)
    }
  }else {
    while(c.length < number){
      await moveDisk(a, b, c, number, 1);
      await moveDisk(a, c, c, number, 2);
      await moveDisk(b, c, c, number, 1);
    }
  }
};



// move disk function, parameters are start, destination, finsh peg and distance between start and destination
async function moveDisk(a, b, c, number, distance) {
    if (c.length == number) return;

    if(!a.length && b.length){
      await draw(b, a, distance*-1);
      a.push(b[b.length-1]);
      b.pop();
    } else if (!b.length && a.length) {
      await draw(a, b, distance);
      b.push(a[a.length-1]);
      a.pop();

    } else {
      if(a[a.length-1] < b[b.length-1]){
        while(a[a.length-1] < b[b.length-1]){
          await draw(a, b, distance);
          b.push(a[a.length-1]);
          a.pop();
        }

      } else if(b[b.length-1] < a[a.length-1]){
        while(b[b.length-1] < a[a.length-1]){
          await draw(b, a, distance*-1);
          a.push(b[b.length-1]);
          b.pop();
        }
      }
    }
};

//moving function: this should animate the disks
async function draw(a, b, distance){
  num = a[a.length-1].toString();
  disk = document.getElementById(num);

//get current translateX css value and then add the distance between start and destination peg
  regEx = /\.*translateX\((.*)px\)/i;
  translate = disk.getAttribute('style')
  value = parseInt(regEx.exec(translate)[1]) + (distance*400);

    //move disk up 
    disk.style.bottom = "385px";
    await delay(250);
    //move disk to the destination peg
    disk.style.transform = "translateX(" + value +"px)";
    await delay(250);
    //drop disk
    disk.style.bottom = b.length*20 +"px";
    await delay(250);
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.towerOfHanoi {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 400px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.tower1,
.tower2,
.tower3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.stick {
  height: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.disk {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: bottom 250ms ease-in-out, transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="number">
  <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="towerOfHanoi">
  <div class="tower1">
    <div class="stick"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tower2">
    <div class="stick"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tower3">
    <div class="stick"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot! But the problem is that the first move function happens instantly, as it does't have to wait for any promise to resolve after the creation of the disks and therefore it starts at the position of the first move and not at the starting position. The second problem I no face is that there is no delay between the change of the bottom property, so you see the disks going sideways, but not up and down. To demonstrate what I mean, here is the updated link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jakob_mayerhofer/rgx17hps/15/

Comment: Didn't realise that you had those vertical animations. See update of answer. There are still visual glitches but they are unrelated to your question, as far as I can see.